# ECONNREFUSEDfailed to connect to /192.171.1.1 (port 1234) from /:: (port 38220): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sockets

When I try to make a connection with socket  I get this exception:
ECONNREFUSEDfailed to connect to /192.171.1.1 (port 1234) from /:: (port 38220): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

This is only happening in few Android 13 mobiles.

Till now, Socket connection is successfully established in Android 11, Android 12, OnePlus OxygenOs 13.1 & on Redmi Android 13.

But I am facing this socket connection refused error when I tried on Android 13 Samsung galaxy M32, Samsung Galaxy F23.

Pls help me with this

```
try {
            //socketConnection.getSocketHoist().setSoTimeout(10000);
            Log.d("Hoistron:run", "run:Above socket conn line ");
            //make new socket conneciton
            hoistronSocket = new Socket("192.171.1.1", 1234);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getLocalizedMessage();
            Log.d("Hoistron:Except", "run: ECONNREFUSED" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            if(e.getLocalizedMessage().contains("ECONNREFUSED"))
            {
                showFailedDialogBox();
            }
```

This is my code to connect to socket!

I tried connecting to my hoist with tcp/upd app in mobile to check if there is any wrong in the server side, but its working fine there.

Answer (score 0):

The above abnormality is caused mainly because the server ip and port requested by the client socket have not opened the listening thread. The investigation directions mainly include the following:
1：It may be that the server listening thread corresponding to the ip and port has not been successfully started or has crashed;
2：The server ip or port of the client socket connection is wrong;
3：The client socket connects using a DNS name that resolves to the wrong IP;
It may be blocked by the firewall on the server side, but this possibility is relatively low